# WebStorm debugging Issue: All object properties are not shown

Tags: javascript, debugging, webstorm

All object properties are not shown in WebStorm on debugging JavaScript. Is this an issue with WebStorm or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: sorry, what object?

Comment: What's the issue?  If you expand `__proto__` you'll see more.